# Use plink.exe with space in password

Tags: windows, shell, putty, plink

**Scenario:**
Use plink.exe to script PDU using CLI. Manual use of plink.exe works. Scripting with plink does not work.

**Problem:**
When I try to script this it doesn't work because to enter CLI mode of the destination device you have to append " -c" at the end of your password.

*If I run this command:*

```
    plink.exe -ssh -m c:\scripts\apc.txt -l admin -pw password -c 192.168.1.10
```

Plink is confused by the presence of the -c switch. I've tried putting in quotes, double quotes. Nothing seems to work.

**Note.** Running this command works (but it defeats the whole point of scripting since I have to manually type in the password:

```
    plink.exe -ssh -m c:\scripts\apc.txt -l admin 192.168.1.10
    password -c
```

Environment:
Windows Server connecting to PDU

Question:
How can I send the password to plink without it thinking that the " -c" part of the password is an invalid switch?

Comment: Put quotes around `"password -c"`?

Comment: Thank you, but I had already tried that and it did not work. It says "        Further authentication required"

Comment: That means it worked to prevent plink from seeing it but something else about the connection wasn't right.. Verbose output from plink in that situation?

Comment: I added " -v" to the end of the command. 

See screenshot... https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/537012/sshot.jpg

Comment: How does that compare to the `-v` output from the manual password entry `-v` output?

Comment: Basically the same: Using username "admin".
Further authentication required
Further authentication required
admin@192.168.1.10's password:
Sent password
Access granted
Opened channel for session
Started a shell/command
Server sent command exit status 1
Disconnected: All channels closed

Comment: So then does entering the password manually not work either or did using quotes work correctly?

Comment: No, it didn't work either (with a script file) but it does work without a script file (manually typing commands, with quotes around the password & " -c" in the password switch.

Comment: Does the working `-v` output look any different? (By "a script file" do you mean when you run the command from in a script it fails even if you enter the password manually but if you run the command manually it works?)

Comment: You are correct on both.

` -v` looks the same with the password entered manually compared with supplying the password in the command line switch.

The script file is what appears to be the problem, which is odd, considering that there are only two commands being entered.

Comment: So the password seems to be working correctly then. But from the script you still can't get this to work? What are you expecting plink to do in your script? Are you expecting it to drop into an interactive remote session and execute the later script lines in the remote session? (i.e. Script contents of `local 1; local 2; plink; remote1; remote2`?)

Comment: Two simple commands are in the file: `OFF 2` & `exit`

Comment: Are you sure the login is failing and it isn't just the commands/script failing? Can you try some `echo` or similar commands in the script to see if they execute at all?

Comment: Did some reading online and discovered that using 
`<apc.txt` 
as opposed to 
` -m apc.txt` making progress